# Check witch cell is visible UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

i have a a UICollectionView where you can swipe full screen images, like the dating apps, but im showing lets say cats, and I  want to add 1 , to the view number of each cat image if the cell was visual for more the 2 seconds, so the view docent count if the users just swipes tru all images fast, or if they try to swipe to next and there is no more so the "end" cell just bounces back, this should only count as 1 view.

```
override func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
        
        let pageWidth = collectionView.frame.size.width
        let currentPage = collectionView.contentOffset.x / pageWidth
      
            pageControl.currentPage = Int(currentPage)
     
            let image  = self.catsImages[Int(currentPage)]
                
            for cat in self.userCats {
                        
                if cat.file == image.imageName{
                  
                    self.postView(cat:cat)
                            
                    print("postView")
                }
            }
  
   
}
```

Comment: I actually don't understand the code but from what I understand if you just want to know if a cell is shown for more then two seconds. Why don't you use collectionView:willDisplayCell
 & collectionView:didEndDisplayingCell. Simply note the time at willDisplayCell and then compare it with the time at didEndDisplayingCell. If you like you can use a dictionary with index path as a key(Since it confirms Hashable Protocole) and time as the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question right, you have a collectionView laid out in such a way that you are only showing one cell at a time allowing the user to swipe right/left to show previous/next cell.

The part where I'm confused is where you want to keep count of the number of cells viewed for more than 2 seconds or you want to keep a reference of those cells.

Either way, it's feasible.

1. You want to create a timer variable:

```
    var timer: Timer?
    var count: Int = 0 /// If you want to track the number of cells 
    var viewedIndexPaths = [IndexPath] /// Or, if you want to track the indexPaths viewed for more than 2 seconds. You get the idea, you can track whatever you'd like
```

2. Since you are showing one cell at a time, you can use the UICollectionViewDelegate willDisplay function to start your timer:

```
   func collectionView(UICollectionView, willDisplay: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt: IndexPath) {
       timer?.invalidate() // Invalidate timer if it's running to prevent cells that were not seen for more than 2 seconds to be logged
       timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 2, repeats: false) { (timer) in
            /// If you want to keep count do this:
            self.count += 1
           /// If you want to log the indexPaths instead, do this:
            self.viewedIndexPaths.append(indexPath)
       }
   }
```

Also, make sure you invalidate your timer on viewWillDisappear.